# Is there a way of folding from right to left, removing tuples that arent within one move away?

Tags: haskell

I've got a depth-first search that returns all the paths it goes down rather than just a path from start to finish. For example
from `(1,1)` to `(3,5)` it returns this list:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,3),(5,2),(5,1),(4,1),(3,1),(5,4),(5,5),(4,5),(3,5)]
```

What I really want is:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(4,5),(3,5)]
```

`(5,3)` and `(5,4)` are neighbours whereas `(3,1)` and `(5,4)` are not.

```
[(5,3),***(5,2),(5,1),(4,1),(3,1),***(5,4)]
```

Could I fold through accumulating all the tuples that aren't neighbours and remove them from the list?

Comment: so you have some function which produces incorrect result and instead of fixing it you want to fake it because you _know_ how the correct result looks like? isn't it better to produce it right in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by simply making a check to see if two tuples are within 1 of each other:

```hs
neighbors :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Bool
neighbors (a, b) (c, d) = abs (a - c) <= 1 && abs (b - d) <= 1
```

Note that, if you can't be 1 away in both directions at the same time, consider using the following implementation:

```hs
neighbors :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Bool
neighbors (a, b) (c, d) = diff1 + diff2 <= 1
    where diff1 = abs (a - c)
          diff2 = abs (b - d)
```

Now you can fold where the accumulator is the final list, so the head of the accumulator would be the element you want to be neighbors with:

```hs
neighborsOnly :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
neighborsOnly list = foldr (\val acc -> 
    if null acc || neighbors (head acc) val
        then val:acc
        else acc) [] list
```

The `null acc` check is for the first iteration, where the accumulator is still an empty list, in which case it should always be considered a neighbor.

Comment: Your second `neighbors` function seems overly complex.  Why not simply check that the sum of the diffs is less than or equal to 1, as in: `neighbors (a, b) (c, d) = abs (a - c) + abs (b - d) <= 1`.  Or actually, can a node be a neighbor of itself?  Perhaps `<=` should really be `==`.